# Postgresql pgAdmin page is not showing as expected. It looks unformatted

Tags: database, postgresql, installation, pgadmin

My problem is related with pgAdmin. Every time I open it, the page looks unformatted. The options within don't work either.

Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qvpQ.png)

Comment: Open the Developer Console of your browser and check for errors?

Comment: It's hard to guess what could be wrong with that little information.